# GtkButton specification

Tags: c++, unix, gtk

Hi guys recently i'm working on a program that use a guy. Because i love linux and other unix system i'm developing it using gtk library and working with them i'm not understand how set the position of a widget into own container and how set the size (width and heigth) of him. Thanks

Comment: You should read some widget packing tutorials first. In [C](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/data_files/public/doc/gtk/tutorial/gtk_tut-4.html). In [Python](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtk2/gtklayoutmanagement/).

Comment: @theGtknerd Not sure where you found that link for GTK and C, it is nearly 17 years old and for GTK 1. Better using http://zetcode.com/gui/gtk2/ for GTK+ 2 or better still use https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/c.html.en which are demos for GTK+ 3.

Comment: Sorry @Errolvandel'Isle but your links only provide general documentation. My links specifically deal with how to layout Gtk widgets, which is what the question is as far as I could tell from the broken English. Perhaps you know a link for packing Gtk3 widgets complete with screenshots and code?

Comment: @theGtknerd the examples you linked to almost certainly haven't compiled with current GTK+ in many years.

Comment: @jku I extend the invitation to you also. Could you provide a complete tutorial in Gtk3 with screen shots and code that shows how to pack Gtk widgets? I provided links that show how widget packing works. There is no guarantee to the code itself.

Comment: Since @P.Calino is using C++ as indicated in the tags, he could use gtkmm the C++ bindings. There is an online book at https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/index.html with a section starting at https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/chapter-container-widgets.html.en just on containers.

Comment: For C and GTK+ 2, https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.90/ look under "Packing Widgets" and "Container Widgets".

Comment: Thaks to all. Really